# findByPid is not working for pages_language_overlay mapping

Tags: mapping, repository, typo3, extbase

(I use typo3 4.5 with extbase-extension.)

I was map the pages_language_overlay to my extbase-model

```
Tx_Extension_Domain_Model_ModelName {
    mapping {
        tableName = pages_language_overlay
    }
}
```

I created a model Tx_Extension_Domain_Model_ModelName with some setters and getters. after adding the repository Tx_Extension_Domain_Repository_ModelNameRepository with

```
public function initializeObject() {
    $this->defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->create('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Typo3QuerySettings');
    $this->defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
}
```

and inject the repository like this

```
public function injectModelNameRepository(Tx_Extension_Domain_Repository_ModelNameRepository $modelNameRepository) {
    $this->modelNameRepository = $modelNameRepository;
}
```

i can not select entries with findByPid. I was testing it with findByUid and echo the pid and it works, but i get no results with findByPid.

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have to add

```
public function initializeObject() {
    $this->defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->create('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Typo3QuerySettings');
    $this->defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    $this->defaultQuerySettings->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
}
```

after this it works well. Otherwise the query has a check like

```
AND pages_language_overlay.sys_language_uid IN (0,-1)
```

in the where clause.